# Java groupingBy List

Tags: java

```
class Student {
    List<Integer> grades
}
```

I want grouping students by grades but groupingBy would work if each student had only one grade. Is any other lamba way to do it? I expect result like 
`Map<Integer, List<Student>>`

Comment: Why do you want to use `groupingBy`?

Comment: I don't want to use groupingBy because it dosnt work...

Comment: And what ist the problem now? Make two loops, the one outer loop over students, the inner loop over their grades and insert the student in the map-entries of their grades.

Comment: Why not use simple loops?

Answer (score 0):

`groupingBy` will do the job if you help it: you might find an equivalent version of this in the Javadoc for [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

```
final List<Student> students = ...;
// @formatter:off
students.stream()
        .flatMap(student -> student.grades.stream()
                                          .map(grade -> new StudentGrade(student, grade)))
        .collect(groupingBy(StudentGrade::getGrade, mapping(StudentGrade::getStudent, toList())));
// @formatter:on
```

Now, you get a `Map<Integer, List<Student>>`. It is up to you to filter duplicates.

You will need these imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Class `StudentGrade` is simple:

```
class StudentGrade {
  private final Student student;
  private final Integer   grade;
  public StudentGrade(Student student, Integer grade) {
    this.student = student;
    this.grade = grade;
  }
  public Student getStudent() {return student;}
  public Integer getGrade()   {return grade;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer, List<Student>> collect = students.stream()
                                                  .flatMap(student -> student.grades.stream()
                                                                                    .map(grade -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(grade,
                                                                                            student)))
                                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey(),
                                                          Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Because Java do not have Pair tuple implementation I used `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

Comment: generally my solution is same as @NoDataFound pointed out. In my proposal you use existing implementation `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`. From the point of code readabulity the @NoDataFound solution, with custom class, is more readable.